# Sorting parent elements based on children's HTML

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, sorting

It's been a while since I've coded, so I'm kind of at a loss right now.

## The Situation

I'm populating a table (or rather a grid) on my website with data from a database. Below is the structure of the code:

```css
#table {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div class="container" id="1340firstitem">
    <text class="channel-pop">  100,022         </text>
    <text class="channel"    >  @1340firstitem  </text>
    <text class="hashtag-pop">  1,100           </text>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="second_item">
    <text class="channel-pop">  555             </text>
    <text class="channel"    >  @second_item    </text>
    <text class="hashtag-pop">  49              </text>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="3rd.item">
    <text class="channel-pop">  100,022        </text>
    <text class="channel"    >  @3rd.item      </text>
    <text class="hashtag-pop">  49             </text>
  </div>
</div>
```

Whereby the information is displayed on the page like so:

```
______C1____|________C2________|____C3______
   100,022  |  @1340firstitem  |  1,100
       555  |  @second_item    |     49
   100,022  |  @3rd.item       |     49
```

Whereas the content of `C2` or `class="channel"` elements is **always** unique, **sometimes** the content of `class="channel-pop"` and `class="hashtag-pop"` elements will be the same.

## The Goal

I would like to be able to sort and re-sort the data in the grid alphabetically based on the value of `class="channel"` (A-Z and Z-A) and numerically based on the values of `class="channel-pop"` and `class="hashtag-pop"` (0-1 and 1-0). However, I'm having a brain fart as to how I would go about doing this.

Eventually the database will become quite dense, so I need to do this as efficiently as possible -- not looping through nested arrays or using loop within loops within loops...

## The Approach

Since the data in `C1` and `C3` is not always unique, I know I need to map the children elements or their content to the parent `container`, which I can do using the `data-` attribute, objects in JS, the map object, etc.

I'm not entirely familiar with map objects, so currently, when the page loads, I'm adding `data-` attributes to the parent container like so:

```html
  <div class="container" id="1340firstitem"
    data-channel-pop="100,022"
    data-hashtag-pop="1,100"
  >
    <text class="channel-pop">  100,022         </text>
    <text class="channel"    >  @1340firstitem  </text>
    <text class="hashtag-pop">  1,100           </text>
  </div>
```

However, of course when I loop through the `container` class and create an array of these `data-` attributes, the value of the `data-` is once again disassociated from the parent element.

***I haven't coded in a while, so I'm struggling to wrap my head around this right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.***

Comment: I believe that a good ammount of work could be saved if you had your table layout better structured.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru sorry, i was in the midst of editing the post when you submitted your revision

Comment: @user7393973 not the point of the question, but enlighten me...

Comment: There are countless ways of doing this, and it seems you aren't having a problem with any of them because you haven't made it that far. I think you need a tutorial, not Q/A.

Comment: @z5h like i said, i'm having a brain fart. i've done this before in the past, but it's been ages since i last coded. some help instead of useless comments would be appreciated

Comment: There's no `text` element in HTML

Comment: @powerbuoy yes, there are o:

Comment: No, there isn't https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element

Comment: @powerbuoy In fact, according to the HTML5 specification, you can create your own elements.Ex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

Comment: @powerbuoy it works just fine [codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/GQdgJY?editors=1111)

Comment: I know you can, but I only pointed out that in the HTML specification there is no such element.

Comment: @powerbuoy so what was the point of pointing that out? i smell BS

Comment: @Anthony I've created a pen that does a simple sort. it does not sorts number correctly. Maybe it's a start. https://codepen.io/Rechousa/pen/vdjELr

Comment: @PedroMartins i'll be able to figure out how to sort numerically if you've already done the alphabetical sort thanks so much for being the only helpful one <333

Comment: Updated, sorry, I've forgot the link :)

Comment: @PedroMartins is it possible u can translate that to JS? it's been even longer since i practiced jQuery lol

Comment: I was just curious why you'd choose to create your own `text` element instead of sticking to standards, and frankly my initial though was that you didn't know that `text` was made up.Imo we have several perfectly suitable elements for "text" already, like `h1` - `h6` as well as `p`. But imo the data you're presenting is perfectly suitable for the good old `table` element. And if you're willing to add jQuery to your code (not that I'm promoting it) you could use one of the many table sorting plugins available, for example: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: @powerbuoy well, for one, browsers apply specific styling to such elements... i could've used `div` elements, but `text` elements adds clarity to the markup. yeah, i'm not interested in using plugins. would rather just code it myself

Comment: I agree with @powerbuoy. Althought you don't code for a while, it would be great for you if you learn jQuery. And stick to the standards. And use many of the plugins (like https://datatables.net/). They are so commonly used and they are for a reason. They are well tested and are great! I'm converting the pen to vanilla js for fun.

Comment: @PedroMartins i understand almost all of it, but, for instance, it took me a second to understand what the `.asc` property is and i don't believe there's an equivalent in JS. also, i'm wasn't too sure what the `find` method did. althought what seems to be happening in that chain of methods is you're creating an array of `container` elements then sorting it.

Comment: @PedroMartins if i remember correctly i used nested arrays back in the day to do this, but i'm not sure that's the most efficient way

Comment: Pen https://codepen.io/Rechousa/pen/vdjELr updated to plain javascript. Hope it helps.

Comment: @PedroMartins love you <3 it seems incredibly complex for a somewhat simple task, although maybe more efficient than using nested arrays

Comment: Thanks, but give it a try for jQuery. You'll love it. It's simple and there are tons of awesome plugins customizable and/or ready to use.Cheers

Comment: @PedroMartins i'm so baffled, where the hell does this `.asc` property come from? is that just a custom property?

Answer (score 1):

> However, of course when I loop through the container class and create an array of these data- attributes, the value of the data- is once again disassociated from the parent element.

This looks like a design error. Create an array of sortable container object data, say like:

```
const gridRows = Array.from(
                    document.getElementById("table")
                    .querySelectorAll(".container")
                 ).map ( container => [
                             container,
                             container.children[0].textContent.trim(),
                             container.children[1].textContent.trim(),
                             container.children[2].textContent.trim()
                         ]
                 );
```

This is an example only* and creates an array of inner arrays of the form

```
 [ containerDOMobject, columnOneText, columnTwoText, columnThreeText]
```

(**The mapping function could be optimized to avoid creating three children node lists, the mapped element is presented as an array for simplicity.*)

Sort the `gridRows` array in any way needed. When replacing a container object in the DOM, using the DOM object reference value from the sorted `gridRows` array, you don't need to remove it first - appending (to the same parent in this case) will move an existing DOM object rather than duplicating it.

---

**A Worked Example**

A variation of `gridRows` preparation could convert numeric entries into numbers for sorting purposes. The reason for creating `gridRows` in the first place was to simplify and expedite sorting - as one commentator noted, there are multiple ways of achieving your goal.

Updating the display is done by appending `container` items to the `#table` element in sorted order. It retains use of `<text>` elements but not `display:grid` layout. How to sort the contents of a `display:grid` element merits a separate question.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    let ascending = 1;
    let sortColumn = undefined;
    let uniqueColumn = document.getElementById("channelColumn").dataset.value;

    const gridRows = Array.from(
            document.getElementById("table")
            .querySelectorAll(".container")
        ).map ( container =>
        {
            const children = container.children;
            let data = [
                container,
                children[0].textContent.trim(),
                children[1].textContent.trim(),
                children[2].textContent.trim()
            ];
            for( var i of [1,3]) {
                data[i] = Number( data[i].replace(",", ""));
            }
            return data;
        });

    function compareRows( aRow, bRow) {
        let a = aRow[sortColumn];
        let b = bRow[sortColumn];
        if( a > b) {
            return ascending;
        }
        if( a < b) {
            return -ascending;
        }
        a = aRow[uniqueColumn];
        b = bRow[uniqueColumn];
        if( a > b) {
            return ascending;
        }
        if( a < b) {
            return -ascending;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    function sortGrid( event) {
        let target = event.target;
        let column = target.dataset.column;
        let table = document.getElementById("table");
        
        if( column) {
            ascending = column === sortColumn ? -ascending : 1;
            sortColumn = column;
            gridRows.sort( compareRows);
            gridRows.forEach( data => table.appendChild(data[0]));
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("sortBy").addEventListener("click", sortGrid);
});
```

```css
#table: {
}
#sortBy {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: teal;
   border-bottom: medium solid grey;
   cursor: default;
}
text {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 30%;
   text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div id="sortBy"><!-- table header -->
<text data-column="1">channel-pop</text>
<text id="channelColumn" data-column="2">channel</text>
<text data-column="3">hashtag-pop</text>
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="1340firstitem">
<text class="channel-pop">  100,022         </text>
<text class="channel"    >  @1340firstitem  </text>
<text class="hashtag-pop">  1,100           </text>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="second_item">
<text class="channel-pop">  555             </text>
<text class="channel"    >  @second_item    </text>
<text class="hashtag-pop">  49              </text>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="3rd.item">
<text class="channel-pop">  100,022        </text>
<text class="channel"    >  @3rd.item      </text>
<text class="hashtag-pop">  49             </text>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as i stated in the question, i really don't understand map objects too well, although i had a gut feeling map objects would probably be the best route. ill have to read more about them.

Comment: `Map` objects created by the [Map constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) are a totally different thing to the [map method of Array objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).  I've used the latter - all it does is transform one array into another using a user supplied transform function, without needing to write a `for` loop :)